# is there any Symfony listeners do sockets work?

Tags: php, function, sockets, symfony, loops

How can I create a listener in Symfony to do such as the sockets do in the following example:

```
public function socketestAction($sizeData)    //For TEST
    {
        session_write_close();
        ob_implicit_flush(true);
        ob_end_flush();

        $offset = 0;
        $limit = 3;
        $sizeData /= $limit;

        // Init IPC connection
        $server = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.1:8000", $errno, $errorMessage);
        if ($server === false) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException("Could not bind to socket: $errorMessage");
        }

        for( $i = 0; $i < $sizeData; $i++)
        {
            // Check our socket for data
            $client = @stream_socket_accept($server);
            if ($client) {
                // Read sent data
                $data = fread($client, 1024);

                // Probably break
                if ($data === 'stop') {
                    break;
                }
            }

            $offset += $limit;
            var_dump($offset);
        }
        // Close socket after sending all messages
        fclose($client);
    }
```

**StopAction :**

```
public function stopAction()
{
    $socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://127.0.0.1:8000');
    fwrite($socket, 'stop');
    fclose($socket);

}
```

But the problem here, is that the port must be changed for every socket, & can't use many sockets at time.. and also it's taking much time to execute !
an other question : Is there any possibility to create a simple txt file instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the EventEmitter extension,download it from github
https://github.com/christopherobin/EventEmitter